# Unable to make recursive call to same subroutine using perl switch statement

Tags: perl, recursion, switch-statement

I am using switch statement to check the argument provided on the terminal.
The provided script is working fine if the end user provide

```
      $perl test.pl -help
```

but when user is giving the under below option it subroutine is not getting called recursively.

```
      $perl test.pl -link abc -web test.com
```

Plz suggest!

```
      use Switch;
      #perl test.pl -help
      #perl test.pl -link abc -web test.com

      sub CheckArgument {

       my ($argv)   = shift @_;
       local $\     = "\n";
       print "\$argv : $argv\n";

       switch($argv) {
                  case /-help/ {
                             print "Usage : $0 -link <link name> -web <website name>";
                             print "Usage : $0 -list_web_name";
                             exit;
                  }
                  case /-list_web_name/ {
                             print "Currently Support following site";
                             foreach (qw/abc/) {
                                        print "$_";
                              }
                             exit;
                   }
                  case /-link/ {
                             CheckArgument($ARGV[3]);
                  }
                  case /-web/ {
                             print "argument provided : @ARGV\n";       
                  }
                  default {
                             CheckArgument("-help");
                  }
        }
       }
```

Comment: Why don't you use GetOpt::Long?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Switch](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Switch) is an experimental module not meant for actual use. 5.10 introduced a switch statement in the form of `given`/`when`.

By the way, you might want to look at [Getopt::Long](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Getopt%3a%3aLong) to handle some of that work far better.

Comment: Actually, in Perl 5.17, they decided that [`given`/`when` is experimental, too](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commitdiff/0f539b13d39feb3bad9b2c86a57dea5035124802).

Comment: @cjm, No, just smart matching. The problem with smart-matching are two-fold: it derives type information from storage format, and it doesn't necessarily provide what a person expects of X ~~ Y. Instead, use of objects that overload smart-matching is promoted, so you can do `X ~~ any(Y)` and some such.

Comment: I don't have 5.17.X installed, but it's my understanding that `given` itself got marked experimental.  (Although I'm not sure how you can mark something experimental 4 major releases after it was first introduced.)

Comment: hum, after a second look, I think it give a warning because it's smart-matching is usually used implicitly with it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the `Switch` source filter is deprecated. Please do not use it.

Here is a rewrite of your code without recursion that may be easier to understand:

```
use 5.010;
sub CheckArgument {
  my $_ = shift;

  ARG: {
    if (/-help/) {
      say "Usage: $0 -link <link-name> -web <website-name>";
      say "Usage: $0 -list_web_name";
    } elsif (/-list_web_name/) {
      say "Currently supporting following sites:";
      say for qw/a b c/;
    } elsif (/-link/) {
      $_ = $ARGV[3];
      redo ARG;
    } elsif (/-web/) {
      say "arguments provided : @ARGV\n";       
    } else {
      $_ = "-help";
      redo ARG;
    }
  }
  exit;
}
```

If we set `@ARGV` to `qw/ -link x y -web/`, and invoke that sub with the `@ARGV` as arguments, we would get following output:

```
arguments provided : -link x y -web
```

First, we look at `-link`. This causes us to put the 4th element in `@ARGV` to the variable we are looking at. This will hold `-web` on the next iteration, which will output all command line arguments. This parsing strategy is in no way robust.

Better than recursion would be to loop while you have unprocessed arguments. If wou recognize a switch, remove the switch and its values from the arglist. When you don't understand an argument, print the usage:

```
use 5.010;
# I use 5.010 for the C<say> function, but if we're already using it,
# we could just as well use given/when. Wouldn't make it much prettier.
sub ProcessArguments {
  ARG: while (@_) {
    my $_ = shift;
    if (/\A-?-list_web_name\z/) {
      say "Currently supporting following sites:";
      say for qw/a b c/;
    } elsif (/\A-?-link\z/) {
      my $link_name = shift;
      shift() =~ /\A-?-web\z/ or do { Usage(); exit };
      my $website_name = shift;
      do_something_with($link_name, $website_name);
    } elsif (/\A-?-web\z/) {
      my $website_name = shift;
      shift() =~ /\A-?-link\z/ or do {Usage(); exit };
      my $link_name = shift;
      do_something_with($link_name, $website_name);
    } else {
      Usage();
      exit;
    }
  }
}
sub Usage {
  say "Usage: $0 -link <link-name> -web <website-name>";
  say "Usage: $0 -list_web_name";
}
```

Oh, this awful boilerplate, the endless repetition. Wouldn't it be great if somebody had already written a something that already gets options for us? Like, a CPAN module?

```
use Getopt::Long;
use 5.010;
sub ProcessArguments {
  my $list_web_name;
  my $help;
  my ($link_name, $website_name);
  GetOptions
    'list-web-name' => \$list_web_name,
    'help'          => \$help,
    'link=s'        => \$link_name,
    'web=s'         => \$website_name;
  if ($help) {
      Usage();
  } elsif ($list_web_name) {
      say "Currently supporting following sites:";
      say for qw/a b c/;
  } elsif (defined $link_name and defined $website_name) {
      do_something_with($link_name, $website_name);
  } else {
      Usage();
  }
}
```

And thats a way its done.